# heoku is not finding ws (websocket)

Tags: javascript, heroku

I have an [App](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app) that locally works.

```
$env:ENV="local"
npm run dev
```

Its [Package.json](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/blob/main/package.json)

```
  {
"name": "forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app",
"version": "0.3.3",
"description": "Autodesk Forge Viewer Data Visualization Sample Application",
"main": "server/localserver.js",
"engines": {
    "node": "14.19.2"
},
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd server && npm install",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run watch\" \"npm run start\" \"nodemon server/localserver.js --delay 300ms --ext js,jsx\"",
    "start": "ws -p 9081",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev-client": "npm install && concurrently --kill-others \"npm run watch\"  \"npm run start\"",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
},
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app.git"
},
"author": "Autodesk Inc.",
"license": "MIT",
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.41",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.13.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.1",
    "css-loader": "3.6.0",
    "local-web-server": "4.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.4.0",
    "node-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "2.0.7",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "svg-url-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@hig/theme-data": "^2.17.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "chronos-etu": "3.1.0",
    "codemirror": "^5.61.1",
    "echarts": "^4.9.0",
    "echarts-for-react": "^2.0.16",
    "forge-dataviz-iot-data-modules": "0.1.11",
    "forge-dataviz-iot-react-components": "0.1.17",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "pixi.js": "^5.3.7",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "react-codemirror2": "^7.2.1",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-rnd": "^10.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^3.0.4",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.4",
    "ws": "^6.2.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
    
}
```

}

Procfile // IS IT OK???

```
$env:ENV="local"
web: npm run dev
```

Error

```
heroku logs --tail

 2022-06-01T05:23:27.918673+00:00 app[web.1]: > forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app@0.3.3 start /app
2022-06-01T05:23:27.918673+00:00 app[web.1]: > ws -p 9081
2022-06-01T05:23:27.918674+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-06-01T05:23:27.929836+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ws: not found
2022-06-01T05:23:27.935528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-06-01T05:23:27.935911+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2022-06-01T05:23:27.936120+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2022-06-01T05:23:27.936316+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2022-06-01T05:23:27.945101+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app@0.3.3 start: `ws -p 9081`
2022-06-01T05:23:27.945232+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2022-06-01T05:23:27.945381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2022-06-01T05:23:27.945506+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app@0.3.3 start script.
2022-06-01T05:23:27.945622+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Someone please download app (if required) from link to findout this problem.

I tried:

```
    1: npm install --save ws
    2: npm install --save ws@6.2.2
    3:put it in package.json // originally it was not there.
    4:delete node modules and installed again
    5: delete app and made new one
```

But the error is still there. How can I make it work on Heroku?

Comment: `ws` doesn't appear to be installed. Try `npm install --save ws` and redeploy to ensure it is.

Comment: I don't think you want `-g`. That's a global install, which'll be on your local machine. `ws` should show up as a dependency in your app's `package.json` for this to work.

Comment: Your edit says you tried `npm install --save ws@6.2.2 -g -D` and 
`npm install --save ws@6.2.2 -g`, but I want you to try `npm install --save ws`. Do that, please. **No `-g`!**

Comment: @ceejayoz Please download app (if required) from link to findout this problem. I tried npm install --save ws also. Now it is my 38th time. No success.

Comment: The `ws` package isn't in your `package.json` at that link. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-dataviz-iot-reference-app/blob/022bbb6034e9f4062153f58317ad3a169ea09603/package.json

Comment: @ceejayoz I know.  Please see edited question.

Comment: @ceejayoz Can you please check this issue. I stuck to this issue.